# Initializing a global, const POD struct; addressing specific members

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/time.h.html
says that

> The  header declares the structure timespec, which has at
>   least the following members:
>        time_t  tv_sec    seconds long
>        tv_nsec   nanoseconds

I'm working with this in C++, and I would like to do the following:

```
//global scope
const /*struct*/ timespec ARMAGEDDON = {
    .tv_sec = std::numeric_limits<decltype((timespec().tv_sec))>::max(), 
    .tv_nsec = std::numeric_limits<decltype((timespec().tv_nsec))>::max(), 
};
```

While C++ allows me to rather flexibly get the maximums of the respective struct members (unlike plain C, as far as I know), I can't use the `.member = value,` C syntax to address the particular members I want.

```
const /*struct*/ timespec ARMAGEDDON = {
      std::numeric_limits<decltype((timespec().tv_sec))>::max(), 
      std::numeric_limits<decltype((timespec().tv_nsec))>::max(), 
};
```

happens to compile, but AFAIK, this initializes the first two members.
The API provider doesn't say `.tv_sec` and `.tv_nsec` are the first two members.

What is the correct way to initialize the struct in C++?

Comment: Have you considered something like `const timespec ARMAGEDDON = InitTimeSpec();` and have `InitTimeSpec` initial each member individually.

Comment: you should probably tag this `C++11` if that's what you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to clutter your global namespace and want to have something resembling C-style initialisation, you can always construct and object using lambda expression.

```
const timespec ARMAGEDDON = []() -> timespec {
    timespec result;
    result.tv_sec = std::numeric_limits<decltype(result.tv_sec)>::max();
    result.tv_nsec = std::numeric_limits<decltype(result.tv_nsec)>::max();
    return result;
}();
```

EDIT: If your compiler is fairly up to date, you should be able to use a slightly shorter construct:

```
const timespec ARMAGEDDON = [](){
    timespec result;
    result.tv_sec = std::numeric_limits<decltype(result.tv_sec)>::max();
    result.tv_nsec = std::numeric_limits<decltype(result.tv_nsec)>::max();
    return result;
}();
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
timespec ARMAGEDDON;
ARMAGEDDON.tv_sec = ...;
ARMAGEDDON.tv_nsec = ...;
```

If you really want it to be `const`, you can move that into a function:

```
timespec makeArmageddon() {
    timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = ...;
    ts.tv_nsec = ...;
    return ts;
}

const timespec ARMAGEDDON = makeArmageddon();
```

Since the API just says it has *at least* those members, without even specifying that they are the *first two* members, I'd just as soon avoid aggregate initialization. Yes, designated initializers would be great here - but I'd still rather be writing C++.

Comment: Interesting. I thought this wouldn't work at the global scope but it does. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid cluttering global namespace consider defining `makeArmageddon` in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr `static` also does that nicely (a little more elegantly than anonymous namespaces, IMO).